# Regex to match variable number of annotations

Tags: regex

I have a string that has variable number of annotations, the goal is to get

> (1) the annotation type,
>
> (2) the annotated string, and
>
> (3) get the original string without annotation.

e.g., Let's try /A_RESTAURANT(Burger King). It is at /A_LOCATION(DOWNTOWN Chicago).

I was able to write regex to match single annotations. But has no clue to do multiple annotations.

```
(.*)\/(A_.*)\((.*)\)(.*)
```

Comment: In your given example, can you provide information, which is (1) the annotation type, (2) the annotated string, and (3) the original string without annotation

Comment: What about `([^\/]*)\/(A_\w+)\(([^()]*)\)`? See https://regex101.com/r/tYV24F/1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to get your goals:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"/A_(?P<a_type>[^()]*)\((?P<a_string>.*?)\)")

def process(text):
    def helper(matchobject):
        annotations.append((matchobject['a_type'], matchobject['a_string']))
        return matchobject['a_string']

    annotations = []

    clean_text = regex.sub(helper, text)

    return clean_text, annotations
```

A test:

```
text = "Let's try /A_RESTAURANT(Burger King). It is at /A_LOCATION(DOWNTOWN Chicago)."

clean_string, annotations = process(text)

print(clean_string)
print(annotations)
```

Output:

```
Let's try Burger King. It is at DOWNTOWN Chicago.
[('RESTAURANT', 'Burger King'), ('LOCATION', 'DOWNTOWN Chicago')]
```